# SQL Statement not working when executed through procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, procedure

Trying execute the below query through a procedure.

The query runs well when i run it manually with single quotes in toad, but facing error while running through a procedure.

```
      v_sql :=
         'INSERT /*+ APPEND parallel(p,8)*/
         INTO NDWMTR_REF_PHARM_RX_MTH 
               (week_id,
               PHARMACY_SEQ_NBR,
               SUPPLIER_ID,
               FINAL_STATUS_CD,
               NDW_DATA_USE_QLFR_CD,
               CMF_OTLT_NBR,
               CMF_OTLT_HIST_NBR,
               CLAIM_CNT)
         Select /*+ PARALLEL (8)*/
         case  
         when TRIM(TO_CHAR(rx.SVC_DT, ''DAY'')) = ''FRIDAY''
         THEN CAST(TO_CHAR(rx.SVC_DT, ''YYYYMMDD'') as NUMBER(8))
         ELSE CAST(TO_CHAR(NEXT_DAY(rx.SVC_DT,''FRIDAY''),''YYYYMMDD'') as NUMBER(8)) 
         END WEEK_ID,
         rx.pharmacy_seq_nbr,
         rx.supplier_id,
         rx.final_status,
         rx.ndw_data_use_qlfr_cd,                                                       
         NVL(ph.CMF_OTLT_NBR,00000000) as CMF_OTLT_NBR,
         NVL(rx.cmf_otlt_nbr,00000000) as cmf_otlt_hist_nbr,
         count(rx.claim_id) as CLAIM_CNT
      FROM
      rx_fact_hdr rx
      left outer JOIN V_PHARM_STORE_SEQNO_XREF ph 
      ON rx.pharmacy_seq_nbr = ph.PHARMACY_SEQ_NBR
      where 
         case  
         when TRIM(TO_CHAR(rx.SVC_DT, ''DAY'')) = ''FRIDAY'' 
         THEN CAST(TO_CHAR(rx.SVC_DT, ''YYYYMMDD'') as NUMBER(8))
         ELSE CAST(TO_CHAR(NEXT_DAY(rx.SVC_DT,''FRIDAY''),''YYYYMMDD'') as NUMBER(8)) 
         END = ''g_week_id''
      group by 
         case  
         when TRIM(TO_CHAR(rx.SVC_DT, ''DAY'')) = ''FRIDAY'' 
         THEN CAST(TO_CHAR(rx.SVC_DT, ''YYYYMMDD'') as NUMBER(8))
         ELSE CAST(TO_CHAR(NEXT_DAY(rx.SVC_DT,''FRIDAY''),''YYYYMMDD'') as NUMBER(8)) 
         END,
      rx.pharmacy_seq_nbr,
      rx.supplier_id,
      rx.final_status,
      rx.ndw_data_use_qlfr_cd,
      ph.cmf_otlt_nbr,
      rx.cmf_otlt_nbr';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;
```

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Answer (score 3):

You could avoid duplicating `'` by using:

```
v_sql := q'{

   your-query-that-works-directly-in-TOAD-editor

}';
```

[Rextester demo](http://rextester.com/VDPDU34386)

More info: [Text Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#i42617)

Comment: @KiranDas Please post your specific error message. "Not working" is too general.